# Why am I no longer the leader of my guild?

Tags: castle-clash

I started a guild a while back (about a month ago) and when I went on today I found out that I'm not the leader of my guild.

I never assigned anyone to be the leader of my clan either. Will someone please tell me why I'm not the leader of my clan, and what I can do to fix it?

I have lost the perks that come along with being a leader so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the guild leader is inactive for 30 days, everyone in the guild gets to vote for a new leader. This is the only way leadership can be transferred in a legitimate way.

Of course, there is always a possibility of someone hacking your account to steal leadership, but if they did that, I would assume they would also consume all your heroes and spend all your resources.

Comment: Weirdly enough, I am now a guild leader, but I didn't do anything other than log in everyday!